# Using WMIC in a batch file to uninstall a program

Tags: batch-file, wmic

I am writing a script to uninstall a program. I am utilizing WMIC to do this. When I run the script, it stops immediately after the wMIC command is run. When run it manually everything works fine. My script looks like this:

```
@echo off
title Forcepoint DLP Endpoint
Echo Forcepoint DLP Endpoint
wmic
product where name="Forcepoint DLP Endpoint" call uninstall /nointeractive
```

What should I be added after "WMIC" in order to continue the script?

**This script when entered manually worked:**

```
wmic
product where name="Forcepoint DLP Endpoint" call uninstall
Y
```

Comment: Does wmic have `/nointeractive` global switch?

Comment: I wasn't aware you could use parameters with the `Uninstall` method, `WMIC Product Call /?`. What happens if you run it without the `/nointeractive` parameter

Comment: @Compo It prompts you, asking if you are sure you want to uninstall "X" program. You can either enter Y or N. Entering Y worked normally.

Comment: And when you enter `Y`, does the script continue. If not what is the next line you are expecting should run, because you didn't include it in your snippet, _despite it being relevant to your question_?

Comment: try with `echo Y|wmic product ...` . Tough it should not ask you shuch a thing.

Comment: @Compo when I run the script. After the WMIC it ends up with a wmic:root\cli> when it should just run the WMIC command and then run the "product where name="PROGRAM TO BE UNINSTALLED" call uninstall /nointeractive" command.

Comment: Perhaps you can just [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48527499/edit) to provide the command with the products real `name` string, and your `wmic:root\cli>` is because your `wmic` command should be on the same line as `product` separated by a space.

Comment: @Compo edited to include the real name, along with the command that actually worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```bat
@Echo Off
Title Forcepoint DLP Endpoint
Echo Forcepoint DLP Endpoint
WMIC Product Where "Name='Forcepoint DLP Endpoint'" Call Uninstall /NoInteractive
```

If that doesn't work then perhaps this might:

```bat
@Echo Off
Title Forcepoint DLP Endpoint
Echo Forcepoint DLP Endpoint
Echo Y|WMIC Product Where "Name='Forcepoint DLP Endpoint'" Call Uninstall
```

If the `Echo Y|` doesn't work then you may just have to remove it and accept the yes/no prompt or find another method of uninstall.

Comment: The second method worked on the program I was testing. I ran it as an admin, it popped up, ran the script, replied with a success and then closed the script. I can't imagine why this would not work on the program I am actually trying to uninstall.

Comment: @FRALEWHALE, you would have to contact the developer to verify the uninstallation process for that particular product. There's no single uninstall routine you can use for all products. Perhaps checking the registry for it's official UninstallString may help you.

Comment: I had planned on checking the registry to confirm that it was in fact uninstalled.