# WMIC and .bat not playing nicely

Tags: batch-file, wmic

I am trying to remove PhishAlarm for all of our machines and tried modifying your script, but I just get a window that says PhishAlarm Add-In for about 30 seconds then goes away. 
If I manually run WMIC and paste just the "product where name="PhishAlarm Outlook Add-In" call uninstall /NOINTERACTIVE" then it runs beautifully. However that does not help me in removing it behind the scenes for all the PC's on our domain.

Here is what I am running:

```
@echo off 
Title PhishAlarm Outlook Add-In 
Echo PhishAlarm Outlook Add-In 
wmic product where name="PhishAlarm Outlook Add-In" call uninstall /NOINTERACTIVE
```

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I did not see from Compo what I was missing.  I apologize.  I am really lost and frustrated.  I didn't mean to offend.

Comment: @Squashman.  I deleted my comment of not the answer on the other post.  I am still lost on what syntax I am missing

Comment: Where are the single and double quotes located in [Compo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48528248/1417694).

Comment: Squashman So I did notice that, and I noticed that I did not have some of the same Capital letters.  I changed that and still ended up with the same result.
@Echo Off
Title PhishAlarm Outlook Add-In
Echo PhishAlarm Outlook Add-In
WMIC Product Where "Name='PhishAlarm Outlook Add-In'" Call Uninstall /NOINTERACTIVE

Am I just really dense and missed something else??

Comment: Look again at the **double** and **single** quote placements in the original answer. They're **not** in the proper place in yours. Look where the first double quote is in that answer - what word is to the immediate right of it? Look at the last double quote - what word is to the immediate left of it? Now look at your code. Repeat that process with the first and last single quotes. (Here's a starting hint - you don't have even one single quote (`'`) in your code. Not one. Here's another hint - find the `=` sign in the linked answer, and look where the opening quote is located to its location.)

Comment: I would also add that you should try to ensure that the product you're trying to uninstall is not running at the time you're trying to uninstall it, and mention that you may need to run it 'As administrator' too.